# Ideal postgres index for non unique varchar column

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I need to create a varchar `category` column in a table and search for rows that are belonging to a particular category.

ie. `ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN category VARCHAR(30)`

The number of categories is very small (repeated across the table)
and the intention is to only use `=` in the where clause.

ie. `select * from items where category = 'food'`

What kind of index would be ideal in postgres?
Especially if the table is never expected to be too big (less than 5,000 rows always)

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook usecase for a Hash Index - you have a very small number of distinct values and only use the equality operator to query them. Using a hash index will enable you to index a relatively small hash of the value, which will allow for faster querying.

Comment: I don't think for this use case there will be a noticeable difference between a hash or a btree index.

Comment: would there be a difference if data size was larger?